# Listing folder contents during cd command

Tags: shell, command-line, ls, cd-command

I might be mistaken here, but I was watching someone navigate using the cd command, and without actually executing it, they were able to show the folder contents of the current folder.

So if I type `cd Downloads/Stuff` then, without pressing enter, can I list the content of the Download/Stuff folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the programmable completion feature of the shell. You can simply press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key twice to gain this behavior.

Imagine you type `cd Downkoads/St` and then press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. `St` will be completed to `Stuff` if it is the only folder starting with `St`. If there are other folders starting with `St` in there, you will get a list of them by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice. For example:

```
$ cd Downloads/St<tab><tab>
Stuff/  Stage/  Start/
```

Another example: When you type `cd Downkoads/` and then press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key twice, everything you can `cd` to will be listed:

```
$ cd Downloads/St<tab><tab>
Stuff/  Stage/  Start/  Otherfolder/
```

Answer (score 2):

They were probably pressing tab twice to get filename completion.

What exactly you are shown depends a bit on the shell: zsh, for example, can be configured to show you file date and size as well, and it is clever enough to only show you directories since you can't `cd` into a file anyway.

Example of bash output:

```
$ cd (tabtab)
dira/     dirb/     file.txt
```

Example of zsh output after some customization:

```
[0 1058 9:52:56] ~/temp/tabtest % cd dir
drwxrwxr-x   2 user   group      4096 Oct 3 09:51 dira
drwxrwxr-x   2 user   group      4096 Oct 3 09:51 dirb
```

(zsh completed to `dir` on the first tab since you can't cd into file.txt.)